# Matlab Image too big to fit on screen

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How to solve this issue

Warning: Image is too big to fit on screen; displaying at 50%

> In imuitools\private\initSize at 73
>
> In imshow at 262
>
> In Lab1 at 10

Comment: double-posting your questions is not a good practice (http://stackoverflow.com/q/8585253/501663)

Comment: sorry for that!! I thought maybe this issue is cause by the image is too big!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reduce the size of your image:

```
im=imresize(im,0.5);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is more than one option, you should provide more details for a better answer.

One option is to use a scroll-bar (see http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imscrollpanel.html)

```
hFig = figure('Toolbar','none', 'Menubar','none');
hIm = imshow(someImageData);
hSP = imscrollpanel(hFig,hIm);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! Really appreciate the answer!

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the initial magnification.

```
imshow(I,'InitialMagnification',50);
```